# csrf failure using csrf and Request Context

Tags: python, django, csrf, django-csrf

I have tried all I can gather from the forums, still need help: 
I keep getting the `CSRF token missing or incorrect` error when I submit a form. It used to be working fine and then I made some changes and now I cant get back.. I am using `{% csrf_token %}` and `RequestContext`. I have tried using `reverse`, i checked the `settings.py` middleware for the `csrf middleware`, tried restarting the server, tried using `HttpResponse` instead of `HttpResponseRedirect` and `template.render()`, tried a url path instead of the {% url %} tag. In other parts of my project I am not even using `RequestContext` and it works fine..

signup_page.html:

```
<p>Sign Up Below
</p>
    <form action={% url 'signup_page' %} method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    ....

    Email
    <input type="email" name="email" required="true"><br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="POST">

</form>
```

views.py

```
def signup_page(request):
    template = loader.get_template('user_app/signup_page.html')

    if request.method == "POST":
        ...
        email = request.POST['email']
        kwargs = {
            'username':username, 'password':password, 'first_name':first_name,
            'last_name':last_name, 'email':email
        }
        new_user = User.objects.create(**kwargs)
        new_user.save()

        context = {
            'text':"POST", 'first_name':first_name
        }

        return HttpResponseRedirect(render('signup_page', context, context_instance =RequestContext(request)))
    else:
        return HttpResponse(template.render(RequestContext(request)))
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from user_app.views import signup_page, profile

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^signup', signup_page, name="signup_page"),
    url(r'^profile', profile, name="profile")
]
```

Comment: show urls.py file

Comment: updated with urls.py

Comment: could it be something like when i create a user than somehow django auto logs me in? And so I am already logged in and trying to create a new user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.shortcuts import render

#create your views here
def your_function(request):
    #do whatever you want here...
    context = {'any_data': 'you_want_to_send'}
    return render(request,'your.html',context)
```

Comment: ok this works for some reason but I have no idea why... do you know why the HttpResponse does not work?

Comment: @ratrace123, yes because the render itself is an httpresponse you are wrapping a response object into another response object. That is why the csrf token is getting hidden in the frontend. It would be nice if you accept the answer.

Comment: this even works when i remove the `@csrf_protect` decorator.. its as if the HttpResponse just wont work with `csrf`..

Comment: Yes it will, csrf_protect is default for form submission @ratrace123

Comment: hmm so do you know why using `render` works and `HttpResponse` does not? what brought you to think your solution would work?

Comment: HttpResponse don't set your csrf_token..
Render does.. It is stated in django docs. That's how I know for form submission HttpResponse would not work in this case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136206/discussion-between-subha-py-and-ratrace123).

Answer (score 0):

Add csrf decorator. Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#module-django.views.decorators.csrf

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect

@csrf_protect
def signup_page(request):
   ...
```